# AttributeError: 'PerReplica' object has no attribute 'numpy'

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, text-to-speech

I'm trying to train fastspeech2 from Tensorflow TTS repo.

On single GPU training it is working fine but on multi-GPU training it says that the ***AttributeError: 'PerReplica' object has no attribute 'numpy'***

The file that I'm trying to train is the official fastspeech2 train python file present over [here](https://github.com/TensorSpeech/TensorFlowTTS/blob/master/examples/fastspeech2/train_fastspeech2.py).

My command:

```
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1,2,3 python examples/fastspeech2/train_fastspeech2.py \
  --train-dir ./dump/train/ \
  --dev-dir ./dump/valid/ \
  --outdir ./examples/fastspeech2/exp/train.fastspeech2.v1/ \
  --config ./examples/fastspeech2/conf/fastspeech2.v1.yaml \
  --use-norm 1 \
  --f0-stat ./dump/stats_f0.npy \
  --energy-stat ./dump/stats_energy.npy \
  --mixed_precision 1 \
  --resume ""
```

The error output I get is mentioned below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "examples/fastspeech2/train_fastspeech2.py", line 421, in <module>
    main()
  File "examples/fastspeech2/train_fastspeech2.py", line 413, in main
    resume=args.resume,
  File "/home/mydir/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_tts/trainers/base_trainer.py", line 852, in fit
    self.run()
  File "/home/mydir/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_tts/trainers/base_trainer.py", line 101, in run
    self._train_epoch()
  File "/home/mydir/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_tts/trainers/base_trainer.py", line 127, in _train_epoch
    self._check_eval_interval()
  File "/home/mydir/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_tts/trainers/base_trainer.py", line 164, in _check_eval_interval
    self._eval_epoch()
  File "/home/mydir/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_tts/trainers/base_trainer.py", line 747, in _eval_epoch
    self.generate_and_save_intermediate_result(batch)
  File "examples/fastspeech2/train_fastspeech2.py", line 150, in generate_and_save_intermediate_result
    utt_ids = batch["utt_ids"].numpy()
AttributeError: 'PerReplica' object has no attribute 'numpy'
```

Please help as I'm unable to understand the exact reason for this error to appear on multi-GPU training.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently working with that same repo and came across this error. Unfortunately I don't have a fix for it yet but in the meantime I am using a work around. This error is thrown when the training attempts to evaluate the network. It does this every x iterations depending on what you set eval_internal_steps to in the file "./examples/fastspeech2/conf/fastspeech2.v1.yaml". If you increase this number to something greater than train_max_steps, the function that throws the error is never called.

The function that is throwing this error is generate_and_save_intermediate_result(batch) and from my understanding you can train without it.